# Сборка проекта с NAnt

Tags: c#, сборка

Начинаю осваивать сей полезный инструмент. Кто работает с ним, посоветуйте пожалуйста нормальную графическую оболочку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAnt-GUI: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nantgui.berlios/